# Using strcpy with std::vector

Tags: c++, string, stdvector, strtok, strcpy

I have some trouble using `strcpy` with a `vector` of instances of my own class. Here's the class:

```c
class elemente {  
    char name[5];  
    short val;  
    bool red;  
};
```

So, I made a vector from this class:

```c
vector<elemente> ele(1);
```

But if I try to do this operation:

```c
strcpy(ele.back().name, strtok(line, " "));
```

I always get Segmentation Fault. Why?

I used GDB to debug my program, and the `line` variable is correct, and also if I replace the vector with a normal `char *` everything works fine (The programs doesn't work, but the content is all right).

What can I do?

Comment: Because the result of `strtok` has more than 4 characters?

Comment: You're programming in C++, not C. So get rid of that `strcpy` and `strtok` functions and change the type of `elemente::name` to `std::string`

Comment: Impossible, I checked it with another variable, the result is 2 chars long

Comment: **if I replace the vector with a normal char * everything works fine** That probably just made matters worse, you just didn't realize it :)

Comment: @user2098833: In that case, please post a [test-case](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: This is not a good question. It dangles a tantalizingly small segment of code that possibly has a multitude of problems and we're expected to guess exactly which one occurs here. Ideally your question should include a complete, but still *minimal* example that illustrates your problem. Everything from `int main()` upwards I need to compile and reproduce your problem on my machine.

Comment: my telepathic skills tell me that whatever the line variable is, it isn't writable. strtok mangles the input string while tokenizing

Comment: I agree with @Petesh: chances are that `line` is `"abcd"` or some such, not a modifiable string. In which case, the problem has nothing to do with `vector` or `strcpy`; it's `strtok` that's writing where writing isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using C++, you should use features this language provides you instead of struggling with C-style code. It's good that you decided to use `std::vector` so continue and  use `std::string` for storing strings, `std::istringstream` for creating an input stream that you will read the tokens from and `std::getline` to actually retrieve these tokens.

At first, use an *access specifier* `public` to make the attributes of the `elemente` class available outside the scope of this class and change the type of `name` to `std::string`:

```
class elemente
{
public:
    std::string name;
    // ...
};
```

Then retrieving tokens from the line could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
...

std::vector<elemente> elements;
std::string line("this is my input line");

std::istringstream lineStream(line);
for (std::string word; std::getline(lineStream, word, ' '); )
{
    if (!word.empty())
    {
        elements.push_back(elemente());
        elements.back().name = word;
    }
}
```

And to test this code, you can just print all names stored within elements of this vector:

```
std::vector<elemente>::iterator e;
for(e = elements.begin(); e != elements.end(); ++e)
    std::cout << e->name << ".";
```

outputs:

```
this.is.my.input.line.
```

---

Alternatively you could create a public constructor of your class so that you can construct your elements with properly initialized members:

```
class elemente
{
public:
    elemente(const std::string& s) : name(s){ }
// ...
    std::string name;
    // ...
};
```

Then parsing of tokens would become:

```
for (std::string word; std::getline(lineStream, word, ' '); )
{
    if (!word.empty())
        elements.push_back(elemente(word));
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much, I almost forgot that I am using c++, I shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel :)